# Error build fortran under Yocto

Tags: fortran, yocto

It seems there is some problem to get compiled fortran for Yocto,

I configured my local.conf:

```
FORTRAN_forcevariable = ",fortran"
RUNTIMETARGET_append_pn-gcc-runtime = " libquadmath libgfortran"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gfortran gfortran-symlinks libgfortran libgfortran-dev"
```

And during compilation I got errors:

```
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/6.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.24985)
ERROR: Task (/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_6.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3636 tasks of which 3570 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check the contents of the `/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/6.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.24985` file?

Comment: Can you describe: 1. What is your goal (compile gcc with fortran support, a specific fortran library or program)? 2. The role of the `local.conf` file (link to a suitable section of the yocto docs)?

Comment: Did you use the local.conf.sample example configuration for this? I can see you're using poky but which version (branch/revision) is this?

Comment: my goal is to have scipy recipe under Yocto which requires fortarn to build

Comment: This will be a help https://jumpnowtek.com/yocto/Add-Fortran-support-to-a-Yocto-build.html

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error in rocko. In my case I needed fortran compiler on an imx6 target, so I found this [patch](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=4ac5511f940232a198ebc3e1c012c252d9ddc6fd) for libgfortran.inc, though in my case I override the functions do_configure and do_compile through a libgfortran_7.3.bbappend recipe.

My configuration added in local.conf:

```
# Enable fortran
IMAGE_FEATURES += "tools-sdk"
FORTRAN_forcevariable = ",fortran"
```

Configuration added to my image recipe:

```
FORTRAN_TOOLS = " \
gfortran \
gfortran-symlinks \
libgfortran \
libgfortran-dev \
"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "${FORTRAN_TOOLS}"
```

After building the image and booting the target, I successfully compiled Fortran code in my target imx6 board.

Comment: What code did you use for your do_configure and do_compile methods?